# Dashboard For Home Page in JasperReports Server 5.0

Tags: jasperserver

I wanted to create role based jasper server home pages.
I followed the  [instructions](http://www.jaspersoft.com/how-set-role-based-jasperserver-home-pages) specified and created the same so that when the specified user logs into the system, he would see his home page which would be the dashboard itself.

But when I logged in with the created user, I see the home page which is the specified dashboard but only half of it.i.e, the dashboard has 4 charts, but only the first 2 are displayed.
While creating this dashboard, I had set the guide to 1280*1024.

Is there something else that needs to be done so that the entire dashboard is seen as the home page?[Now only half is being displayed]

I am using JasperReports Server 5.0
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am new to jasper server .   i am also trying to customize it . please u can help me .  shubham.batra17@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, we can set the size of the frame in the newly created home page [jsp].
Height and width can be set as per the requirement in the iFrame section.
The newly created home page will be located in [jasper home]\jasperreports-server-*\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver-pro\WEB-INF\jsp\modules\home